# what does VZIP and VUZP instructions do in ARM assembly

Tags: arm, neon

I was working with some assembly code for ARM's NEON processor and i came across these instructions in my code. I am not able to understand how do these instruction work exactly.. (I MEAN AT THE MEMORY LEVEL..(REGISTER LEVEL)). Any help regarding this would be appreciable. Thank you in advance

```
VZIP.F32    Q3, Q4
VUZP.F32    Q3, Q4
```

Comment: Do the diagrams in [the instruction documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1361289996005.html) demonstrate the interleaving operation clearly enough?

Comment: There is no data type like `F32` for permutation, just the width.

Comment: Like Notlikethat already mentioned, the documentation illustrates the instruction good enough. If you don't understand that, it's probably because you don't understand the concept of SIMD.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/coding-for-neon---part-5-rearranging-vectors) also has a nice presentation of the instructions and shows also some usages. Actually, the whole tutorial is worth a read :)